# finding a value after a selector

Tags: jquery

I have the following html snippet

```
<ul class="product">
 <li><span>Available:</span>123</li>
 <li><span>Code:</span>12345</li>
</ul>
```

What I'm looking to do, is to get the value of of the Available, i.e `123`

I have:

```
var a = $(".product li:contains('Available')").text();
```

But this stores `Available:123`. I only need the numeric value.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: you could always split the `a` variable using the `:` to get your desired value but I'm sure someone will be able to adjust your original selector.

Comment: The simplest solution, although perhaps not the easiest to implement, would be to wrap `123` in another `<span>` with a unique class and use `.find('.classname').text()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function(){

    var a = $(".product li:contains('Available')").clone();
    a.find('span').remove();
    alert(a.html());    

});
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/wrFAh/8/

**EDIT :** The above solution is expecting the `LI` element to have only one type of HTML element other than the number to retrieved, that is the `span`, If you are adding a `div` to the li, this wont work.

To handle this, I would wrap the `Price` in the HTML in a `span` and access it to avoid such problems.

So my HTML will look like

```
<ul class="product">
    <li><span>Available:</span><span class="price">123</span></li>
    <li><span>Code:</span><span class="price">123</span></li>
</ul>
```

And script would be

```
$(function(){    
   var a = $(".product li:contains('Available')").find(".price").html();
   alert(a);
});
```

Sample http://jsfiddle.net/wrFAh/12/

Comment: Much nicer solution than mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can iterate through the child nodes of the `<li>` identified, and use the value of the text node.

```
var myLi = $(".product li:contains('Available')")[0];

var a;
for(var i = 0; i < myLi.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if(myLi.childNodes[i].nodeType === 3) {
        a = myLi.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
    }       
}

alert(a);
```

That's a bit of jQuery to identify the `<li>` you're interested in, then pure Javascript to do the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a selector that will do what you want. Ideally, you would modify your HTML and add classes and another span around the value. If you can't do that, then provided there will always be a colon and a value after, you can use this:

```
var a = $(".product li:contains('Available')").text().split(":")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a regex to extract the number

```
 var a = $(".product li:contains('Available')").text();
 var number = a.match(/[0-9]+/)[0];
```